# Can we use UDF in excel custom validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, vsto, vba

I have added the UDF in my excel template(C#) using excel addin classlibrary,but i can not use that function in custom validation when i use the UDF in custom validation of excel(data->validation->dropdownlist(custom))i get an error as:

> You can not use references to other worksheeta or workbooks for data validation criteria.

Is there any solution to this problem? Can we use UDF in custom validation of excel?

Answer (score 2):

I had forgotten about the UDF-in-data validation restriction.
I think that restriction has been removed in Excel 2010.
Otherwise AFAIK the only way round it is to wrap the UDF in a Defined Name in the xlt
(create a Defined Name in the xlt that references the UDF: NameValidate=MyUDF())

Comment: Can u plz elaborate how to create a Defined Name in the xlt that references the UDF...

Comment: If you have XL 2007 or 2010 use Name Manager on the Formulas Tab -->New, add a Name and set the Refersto=MyUDF(...). If you have Excel 2003 start from Insert-->Name-->Define. However I am not sure if this will work for a UDF in an external workbook.