# How to call VBA function from excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have en excel file where i have to put validation rule. I have one cell let says "customer Time" where user can enter time but it is customize time. User can enter time like that

```
23:45
98:20
100:30
```

User cannot enter string and no special character except colon. I have made one macro and it works perfectly accoriding to customer demand. Here is macro

```
Public Function isValidTime(myText) As String
Dim regEx
Set regEx = New RegExp   'Regular expression object
regEx.Pattern = "^[0-9]+([:]+[0-9]+)*$"  ' Set pattern.
If regEx.test(myText) Then
isValidTime = myText
Else
isValidTime = "Null"
End If
End Function
```

Note: To test this macro you have to go to VBA ide in Tool then reference and then select microsoft visual basic vbascript 5.5

Now i want to call this at excel. I can call like =IsValidTime("23:43") and getting result but customer is not interested to call this. Customer need a excel where he/she enter the value and value will validate according to above criteria and get the exact value or Null.

I dont know how to fix this task. I have Validated date and time as well from Data and then data validation and set the rule and it works perfect, i need the same way for my this rule as well. Any help will be highly appreciated...

Thanks
Kazmi

Comment: You might look at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4647693/471129

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `Worksheet_Change` event inside the sheet. Inside the VBE, select the sheet and choose `Workhseet` from the left drop-down and `Change` from the right.

Enter the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then 'assumes user input cell is A1

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    On Error GoTo ErrTrap

    Target.Value = isValidTime(Target.Value)

End If

KeepMoving:

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

    Exit Sub 

ErrTrap:

    MsgBox Err.Number & Err.Description
    Resume KeepMoving


End Sub

Public Function isValidTime(myText) As String

Dim regEx

Set regEx = New RegExp   'Regular expression object

regEx.Pattern = "^[0-9]+([:]+[0-9]+)*$"  ' Set pattern.

If regEx.test(myText) Then

    isValidTime = myText

Else
    isValidTime = "Null"

End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. I have tested this but not getting exact what i need. Let suppose if i write on cell A1 this value 34:45 then i am getting 10:45 and if i am wriring 34:dd then i am getting the same text not null. Have you tested Scott. I have given challenge to my project manager that I will find out solution. So we are on our way to fix this issue.

Comment: have you tried playing with the format of your input cell? or placing an ''` in front of the entry?

Comment: Yes, It works, we have to change the format of cell as a text. It works. Thank you very much Scott. TC

Comment: @HusnainKazmi -> Great. Please mark as answered so that others can benefit from knowing it worked.

Comment: yes, I will do, but last questions, Its working only on A1, and if i paste the cell on A2 and so on I am not getting the same effect. If i write on A1 this string 23:fa then i am getting Null and its perfect but if i write on A2 the above then i am  not getting null. We have approx 30 elements that need this rule. Can you please tell me this as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @HusnainKazmi -> since this a separate question than your original, you should really post a new question ... however, I'll tell you here.  This line `If Target.Address = "$A$1"` specifies that the code only fires if the change occurs in cell A1. If you want to expand your range or choose different cells, you have to change it. One way to include multiple ranges is to say `If Intersect(Target,Range("A1:A30"))` ...  you can play with from there to get exactly what you need.