# How to get the address of any cell from range in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a macro and calling from excel automatically. The macro is working only for Cell `A1`, I have played with range and tried different things to get the address of `A2` or `A3` so on but no success. We have range like `A1:A30` and as user will give data I want macro to execute automatically and give result.

Here is the link where I can call macro one time or for 'A1' but how do I to use this macro for `A1:A30`?
[How to call VBA function from excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886383/how-to-call-vba-function-from-excel/13894502#13894502)

Answer (score 2):

Replace:
`If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then 'assumes user input cell is A1`

with this:
`If Not Intersect(Target.Parent.Range("A1:A30"), Target) Is Nothing Then`

And make sure to check Scott Holtzman's answer on your other question as correct.